# Is there a timer function in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, timer

I'm looking for a way to call a function every `N` seconds in order to update data displayed on the page.

Is there a built-in functionality to accomplish this task or do I have to do it by myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) and [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) javascript functions. For example:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // this will run on every 10 seconds
    // Here you can send AJAX requests to your controller actions in order 
    // to refresh some data
}, 1000 * 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Timer class:

```
using System.Timers;
...

_timer = new Timer(3000); // Set up the timer for 3 seco
_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
_timer.Enabled = true; // Enable it


static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   // do stuff
}
```